# Particle acceleration position problem (Calculus)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, linear-approximation

A particle's position is given by $x(t) = \cos^2(t) + t$, where time is measured in seconds. Find the particle's approximate position after 6 seconds have passed.

So I find the second derivative, which is:

2(sin^2(t)-cos^2(t))

But the problem tells me: Do not compute exactly here. You should be able to use calculus to get a quick estimate.

So would I use approximation to get this value? How should I approach this?

Comment: Why not just plug in $t=6$ to find the position at $t=6$...?

Comment: Problem tells me not to compute exactly.

Comment: My point: Why are you differentiating?

Comment: Acceleration formula is the second derivative of the function.

Comment: But that is not what the problem asks for. You are asked to find the position, not the acceleration.

Comment: So, should I just use linear approximation to find the position at t=6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63963/discussion-between-vishal-sivamani-and-simply-beautiful-art).

Comment: No. You need to think about what multiple of $\pi$ is close to $6$, then expand there.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that $\cos(6) = \cos(2\pi-6)$ and that $\cos^2(t)\approx \left(1-\frac{t^2}{2}\right)^2\approx 1-t^2$ for small $t$ using the Taylor series approximation of $\cos$. $2\pi-6\approx 0.3$, so $\cos^2(6)\approx 1-0.3^2\approx 0.9$. Therefore, $x(6)\approx 6.9$.